# 'Column' object is not callable in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
def lead_function(df, id_col, subcatid_col, start_date_col, price):  
    window_spec_st = Window().partitionBy(id_col, subcatid_col).orderBy(start_date_col)
    return new_df.select("record_id", "subcat_id", "start_date", "price").withColumn("lead",F.lead(price,1).over(window_spec_st)) 

change_amount_df = lead_function(new_df, F.col("id"), F.col("subcat_id"), F.col("start_date"), F.col("price"))
```

I was try to read my function in spark but I miss with this error:

**TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable**

```
def price_vs_lead(price, lead, id_col, subcatid_col, changes_count_alias="changes_count"): 
    return F.when((price) > (lead), 1) \
            .when((lead) > (price), 2).otherwise(F.lit(0)).alias(changes_count_alias) \
            .groupBy((id_col), (subcatid_col)) \
            .agg(F.count(F.when((changes_count_alias) == 1, 1)).alias("increase"), \
            .count(F.when(F.col(changes_count_alias) == 2, 1)).alias("decrease"))

new_df = change_amount_df.select("*", price_vs_lead(F.col("price"), F.col("lead"), F.col("id"), F.col("subcat_id")))
```

if someone has a good idea of what the problem is with my syntax it will be awesome.

thanks everyone!

Comment: Please add the full traceback to the question.

Comment: the `.count` in the last line should be `F.count` - it is part of the `agg` -- also, your `F.when` is not referencing any df. `F.when` should be within a `select` or `withColumn` given you have a `groupBy.agg`

Answer (score 0):

From the details you've provided I understand that the issue is with the usage of alias in the 'price_vs_lead' function. You are using the 'alias' function as a method on the 'otherwise' function, which is causing the 'Column' object not callable error.

To fix this error, I suggest you move the 'alias' function outside the 'otherwise' function like this:

```
def price_vs_lead(price, lead, id_col, subcatid_col, changes_count_alias="changes_count"): 
    return (F.when((price) > (lead), 1) \
        .when((lead) > (price), 2).otherwise(F.lit(0)) \
        .alias(changes_count_alias)) \
        .groupBy((id_col), (subcatid_col)) \
        .agg(F.count(F.when((F.col(changes_count_alias)) == 1, 1)).alias("increase"), \
        F.count(F.when(F.col(changes_count_alias) == 2, 1)).alias("decrease"))
```

By moving the 'alias' function outside the 'otherwise' function, you can call it on the result of the entire when statement, which is a 'Column' object.

Comment: I was try to do something like this but its with the same error



`def price_vs_lead(price, lead): 
    return F.when(price > lead, 1)\
            .when(lead > price, 2).otherwise(F.lit(0))` 

`def inc_vs_desc(price, lead, id_col, subcatid_col, changes_count_alias="changes_count"): 
    price_vs_lead_df = price_vs_lead(price, lead).alias(changes_count_alias) 
    return (price_vs_lead_df.groupBy(id_col, subcatid_col)
            .agg(F.count(F.when((F.col(changes_count_alias)) == 1, 1)).alias("increase"), F.count(F.when(F.col(changes_count_alias) == 2, 1)).alias("decrease")))`